# Kubernetes IKS cloud | how to get actual hostname of the node from node describe?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-private, iks

In **IKS** platform, the hostname under the Addresses field of a node is not matching with the actual hostname.
Even the label with `kubernetes.io/hostname` is not having an actual hostname.
is it possible to use labels on the node? I see there is one label whose value is matching with the actual hostname. `ibm-cloud.kubernetes.io/worker-id` Anyone from the IBM cloud team(IKS/ICP) can confirm this to rely on it or not.

there is a similar question asked on the same topic, but didn't get satisfactory answer [how to identity k8s node uniquely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317594/how-to-uniquely-identify-a-kubernetes-node-using-kubernetes-api-and-the-node-ope/61318538)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the label `ibm-cloud.kubernetes.io/worker-id`

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any reference doc for this. My concern is that this is label. Should we rely on it? Coz anyone can change the label of the resource. Correct me If I am wrong.